# ThinkCentre m58p (type 7484) will not boot after RAM is replaced

Tags: boot, memory, lenovo-desktop-computer, thinkcentre

I have a **ThinkCentre m58p 7484** I have 12GB of RAM installed 2x2GB and 2x4GB the first sticks came with the machine the second pair I bought online. Now when I have all sticks in their proper place the machine boots just fine with all sticks visible to the system however if I attempt to remove the **original set** from the board leaving the 2x4GB the system will NOT boot the board beeps some and the fans turn all the way up with no prompt whatsoever and I have to unplug the machine in and put the original 2x2GB sticks in before I see the splash screen. Does anybody have any idea what is going on here? What is so special about the original sticks?

Comment: Have you tried putting the 2 4GB sticks into the slots the 2GB sticks occupied?

Comment: @music2myear I might have. IDK at this point I feel like I've tried everything. I'll try that when I get home though.

Comment: Double-check if you cannot recall. Some systems may require certain memory configuration or certain slots be filled to function properly.

Comment: Okay so that works. I'm running the system with the 2x4GB now. Thanks for the suggestion I'm off to buy more RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain systems require memory to be installed in specific slots in order for the system to function.

For instance, if you have 4 slots numbered 1-4, memory MUST be installed in slot 1 (or slots 1 and 2 if dual modules are required) before the computer will work.

This is not the case in every system, but when diagnosing memory issues, it is one of the standard steps to test.

Comment: Thanks again. Also I want to note something strange about the original 2x@GB RAM that was in the 1 and 2 position when I now try those sticks in the 3 and 4 positions the machine refuses to post and the mobo makes a 3-3-3 beep. IDK what is up with this thing hopefully the new sticks will work in those slots.

Comment: It's an old computer. I'd be willing to accept a "gremlins" answer on that one myself. But, I'd try cleaning the RAM contacts first and using GENTLE air to clear the sockets.